# wx.ColourDialog - how to create "FLOAT_ON_TOP" style?

Tags: wxpython

I would like my wx.ColourDialog to be always on top and have the other windows not accessible while it is open - similar to what a wx.FileDialog does. 
The class does not

```
def OnColourChoose(self, e):
    self.dlg = wx.ColourDialog(parent=None)
    self.dlg.GetColourData().SetChooseFull(True)
    if self.dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         col = self.dlg.GetColourData()
```

I tried using "style=wx.FLOAT_ON_TOP" but the class does not support window styles, like wx.FileDialog() does.

Comment: Is there a `wx.FLOAT_ON_TOP`? There's definitely a `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` and a `wx.FLOAT_ON_PARENT` which applies to a `wx.Frame`, so try putting the dialog in a `wx.Frame` of its own

Comment: Does the dialog behave better if you give it “self” as a parent?

Comment: that actually fixed it. I will do further testing though.